# Why we invoke Object.clone() method?

Tags: java, linked-list

This is an implementation of the `SinglyLinkedList.clone` method given in my book.

```
public SinglyLinkedList<E> clone(){
    SinglyLinkedList<E> other =(SinglyLinkedList<E>) super.clone();
     // rest of the implementation. 
}
```

Why we invoked `super.clone()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java API doc of Object.clone(): “this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment”. So I guess the purpose is to create the SinglyLinkedList object that will be the clone.

Comment: By "assignment"  do you mean the "="  operation.  I mean shallow copy?

Comment: I didn’t write it, only copied it for you. But yes, they mean the same as happens with the = operator. This gives you a shallow copy! Go read the rest of the docs yourself to have it spelled out. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: Hello Ole V. V  I am blocked from asking further questions.  So I need you to help with my doubt. Why  Stringbuilder concatenates faster inside loops than Strings.  Sorry for this type of approach.

Comment: Unusual approach, but does it matter? A String concatenation is implemented with a StringBuilder, so each time through the loop will create a new StringBuilder. Do you see that creating a StringBuilder only once will be faster?

Comment: I talking about its complexity,  consider below:

Comment: Case 1:  String s1="a"; for(int i =0; i<N; i++) s1=s1+"c";         Case 2:   StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("a") ;      for(int i =0;i<N; i++) s1.append("c");                                     //When N gets larger we notice Case 2 becomes more efficient.  Case 1 runs in O(n^2) time whereas Case 2 runs in O(n) time.

Comment: The StringBuilder in case 2 will have its buffer extended every time it runs full, which involves copying the entire content, so the time may or may not be O(n) depending on the implementation or extension strategy. Otherwise I believe you are correct.